# How to set passwordToggleEnabled programmatically

Tags: android

I created an `TextInputEditText` programmatically and I set the `inputType` to `textPassword`and it works fine. But, the problem from the last support library we need to add `app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"` to show the password toggle view.

How to set it programmatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap it in a `TextInputLayout` and then you can enable/disable the toggle programmatically.

```
textInputLayout.setPasswordVisibilityToggleEnabled()
```

IIRC this wasn't available in older versions of the design library for some reason, but later updates added it. Make sure you're on the latest version (25.1.0).

Comment: yes this is what i did in the end 
in the documentation ` txtInput.setPasswordVisibilityToggleEnabled(true);` available just for `TextInputLayout`
thank you

Comment: It's now deprecated

Answer (score 6):

Method `setPasswordVisibilityToggleEnabled` is deprecated in current versions of `TextInputLayout`.

You can use following line to enable password toggle icon:

```
textInputLayout.setEndIconMode(TextInputLayout.END_ICON_PASSWORD_TOGGLE);
```

and to again set it back to normal, use:

```
textInputLayout.setEndIconMode(TextInputLayout.END_ICON_NONE);
```

Comment: This is the correct answer now that setPasswordVisibilityToggleEnabled is deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

Also you can try this:

```
textInputLayout.setPasswordVisibilityToggleEnabled(true);
```

Comment: It's deprecated now

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
 if (textInputEditText.getTransformationMethod() == null) {
        textInputEditText.setTransformationMethod(new PasswordTransformationMethod());
        textInputEditText.setSelection(textInputEditText.getText().length());
    } else {
        textInputEditText.setTransformationMethod(null);
        textInputEditText.setSelection(textInputEditText.getText().length());
    }
```